# Set variable in dialog boxes

Tags: scripting, mirc

```
/set %something sadf
```

hmm, can I use combo dialog boxes to set a value to variable?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the value of a variable to be equal to whatever is in a combo box, you just need to add an on dialog event. Here's an example of how to do that

```
dialog combo {

  size -1 -1 100 20
  title "Combo"
  option dbu

  combo 1, 5 5 50 10
  button "Set variable", 2, 60 5 35 10

}

on 1:dialog:combo:sclick:2 { 

  if ($did(combo, 1) != $null) set %something $did(combo, 1)

}

alias combo dialog -m combo combo
```

Run `/combo`, type something in the combo box and press `Set variable`. The `%something` variable will be set with what you typed in.